# /home/user/.zshenv:5: command not found: rustc

Tags: zsh

I have this error: `/home/sugar/.zshenv:5: command not found: rustc`

I installed rust with `modify path: y` and checked with `print $path` and observed `/home/user/.cargo/bin` in first elemnt of `$path` array. So I have no clue why `rustc` is not found. Also tried to add `.cargo/bin` in `.zshrc` instead of `.zshenv` but also didn't work.

Error appears as I have this line in `.zshenv`:

`RUST_SRC_PATH=$(rustc --print sysroot)/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/`

Comment: Did you log out, and then log in again after your changes?

Comment: Still the same error, note that I have this line in `.zshenv` that echo-ing error: `RUST_SRC_PATH=$(rustc --print sysroot)/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/`

Comment: Do you modify $PATH before the line where you did $RUST_SRC_PATH or after it?

Comment: I chose `modify path: y` so I don't know where and when `.cargo/bin` added to `$path`, as I mentioned even I put `RUST_SRC_PATH` in `.zshrc`, still error.

Comment: where is `rustc`?

Comment: Result from command `whereis rustc`: `rustc: /home/user/.cargo/bin/rustc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.zshenv` is interpreted *for every shell invocation* including the ones running scripts **before** `~/.zprofile` (for login shells) or `~/.zshrc` (interactive shell customisation). So if you set `$path` in `~/.zshrc` or `~/.zprofile`, it won't be set yet by the time `zsh` interprets `~/.zshenv`.

Here, it seems you'd want to either customize your login sessions to have `~/.cargo/bin` added to your `$path` and a `RUST_SRC_PATH` environment variable set.

So if `zsh` is your login shell, add:

```
typeset -U path
path+=(~/.cargo/bin)
export RUST_SRC_PATH="$(rustc --print sysroot)/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src"
```

To your `~/.zprofile`. Then, the next time you login, your environment should be properly configured.

Or put those lines in `~/.zshenv` if you want all your `zsh` invocations to have that environment regardless of whether  they were started as part of your login session or not.